# Add "Validation Constraints" to a form which is not attached to an entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I created the following fom class **wihout using an entity** :

```
<?php
// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Form/AdvertType.php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('date',      'date')
      ->add('title',     'text')          
      ->add('save',      'submit')
    ;
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array());
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'my_form';
  }
}
```

I'd like to add a set of Validation Constraints to validate this form.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation)?

Comment: I have done something similar a long time ago. I'll post some code when I find the project...

Comment: Yes i read the documentation, but i created a fom which is not attached to an entity. So is there a solution ? if not, how can i create a not persisted entity which is attached to my form ? I'd like to not create a dedicated table within my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add constraints like this :

```
$builder
    ->add('title', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(['message' => 'Your error message']),
        )
    ));
```

Doc here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html